# Cannot find name 'myVar'

Tags: excel, office-scripts

Using Excel Office Scripts, I'm trying to declare `MyVar` within a for loop:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, varB: string) {
  let ws = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  let rng = ws.getRange("B3:E5")
  let rgnArr = rng.getValues(); 

  for(let i = 0; i <= rgnArr.length - 1; i++){
    if(varB == rgnArr[i][0]){
      let myVar = rgnArr[i][3];
    }
  };

console.log(myVar);

}
```

This returns the error: `Cannot find name 'myVar'` which I believe is because the variable is being declared inside the loop.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `if(varB == rgnArr[i][0])` If this condition is not true in any loop iteration, then `let myVar = rgnArr[i][3];` is never executed and thus the variable does not existy.

Comment: varB is an argument of the main function

Comment: Yes it is.  So what?

Comment: If varB is 'A' and rngArr[I][0] is also 'A' then myVar is declared, right?

Comment: Ignore my comment.  @taller has the right answer.

Comment: Sure, no problem 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The problem is the scope of variables.
- `let myVar = rgnArr[i][3];` is in `if` clause. It is no way to access it out of the scope.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, varB: string) {
    let ws = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let rng = ws.getRange("B3:E5")
    let rgnArr = rng.getValues();
    let myVar:string|number|boolean;
    for (let i = 0; i <= rgnArr.length - 1; i++) {
        if (varB == rgnArr[i][0]) {
             myVar = rgnArr[i][3];
             break;
        }
    };
    console.log(myVar);
}
```

---

- As `varB` is a string, I would suggest to read cells with `getTexts`. `rgnArr` is a string array.
- `if (varB === rgnArr[i][0])` is more reliable.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, varB: string) {
    let ws = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let rng = ws.getRange("B3:E5")
    let rgnArr = rng.getTexts();
    let myVar:string;
    for (let i = 0; i <= rgnArr.length - 1; i++) {
        if (varB === rgnArr[i][0]) {
             myVar = rgnArr[i][3];
             break;
        }
    };
    console.log(myVar);
}
```

Comment: thanks, I tried your second block of code, it ran without errors, but got "undefined", event though I tested with an input that is equal to one of the cells, so I should get the result two cells at the right

Comment: What is the content of the cell? Did you get the right output with the first code block?

Comment: The cell content is a string.There's no difference between the two code blocks, they both return "undefined"

Comment: It seems that the variable myVar is not assigned within the for loop. There must be a way to assign variables within loops..

Comment: It is means the condition `varB == rgnArr[i][0]` is evaluated as False. Adding `console.log(varB, rgnArr[i][0])` in `for` loop to check its value.

Comment: Hi, pls see this other post with a simple example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77600258/define-a-variable-within-a-for-loop-using-officescripts