# Define a variable within a for loop using OfficeScripts

Tags: excel, typescript, office-scripts

Given this OfficeScript:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, myText: string) {
    let ws = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let rng = ws.getRange("B3:C6");
    let rgnArr = rng.getValues();

    let email: string | number | boolean;

    for (let i = 0; i <= rgnArr.length - 1; i++) {
        
        if (myText === rgnArr[i][0]) {
            let email = rgnArr[i][1];
            //break;
        }
    };

    console.log(email);

}
```

In this spreadsheet:

[image]

If I pass `ABC` to `myText`, I should get to the console: `abc@mail.com`

I'm getting `undefined`

Comment: `let email = rgnArr[i][1];` overwrites `let email: string | number | boolean;`. The value of `email` must be `undefined` when `console.log(email);` accesses it.

Comment: So, how to fix it?

Comment: You should use `email = rgnArr[i][1];` in `for` loop.

Comment: That makes more sense. So, let will redefine the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let email = rgnArr[i][1];` overwrites `let email: string | number | boolean;`. There are two variables which have the same name. But they have different scope.

The value of `email` must be `undefined` when the code `console.log(email);` accesses it because it isn't assigned any value.

Fix: Using `email = rgnArr[i][1];` to assign the value in for loop.